# HTML5 canvas flickering, moving object in a stright line and rotate to face mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need help with the following Javascript/HTML5 `canvas`.

1. I need the sprite gun to always faces the mouse pointer, also when moving to keep facing it`s mouse direction, also the bullets it fires too.
2. I want to draw a complete straight lines when firing the bullets.(199 line). I was using a default algorithm, but it does not move the objects in real straight lines.
3. There is a flicker when I clear the canvas rect on the main render thread. (Line 298)
   Note. The left button fires the bullets, the right moves the object.

> I can not upload the file to JSFiddle, because I have local resources.
>   Sorry could not do it. Here is a Dropbox link with the local files.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/giwcz131j1urks9/AAA6aAwnaEd6fvoCeEaIOBjXa?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an error in your Dropbox script `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` in game.js line 169

Comment: I`ve fixed it. Thanks for the info. Now its working.

Comment: sniper.stop() is an error as well

Comment: Firebug does not shows errors for stop() function. Are you sure?

Comment: Its Firefox error on right click: `TypeError: sniper.stop is not a function`
sniper.stop(); game.js (line 233, col 4)

Comment: Ok, but that`s not the problem I am asking for. Also it does not affect anything.